# How do I sort view list results in a crudify lift "page"?

Tags: lift

I am using a CRUDify object to do a simple admin app.  I would like to sort the results that the "list" page displays.  Is there a quick way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out by reading the source:

If you extend CRUDIFY you can override findForListParams to do this.  The following will order by the description field ascending

```
override def findForListParams = {
   List(OrderBy(description, Ascending))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to order using crudify, just add `:order => 'name ASC'`

code:

```
crudify :'refinery/glossaries/glossary',
            :title_attribute => 'name', :xhr_paging => true, :order => 'name ASC'
```

ta.